# Box2d b2World giving me error

Tags: c++, eclipse, box2d

So basically I'm just having trying to get started on using Box2D with eclipse but it keeps giving me error when trying to create the b2World.

I have included Box2D.h

```
b2Vec2 gravity(0.0f, -5.0f);
world = new b2World(gravity);
```

gives
Undefined symbols:
  "b2World::b2World(b2Vec2 const&)", referenced from: blahblahblah"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same problem, and the solution to this is to simply link to the Box2D library when compiling.

Answer (score 0):

The reference manual says you need to

```
#include <b2World.h>
```

Comment: b2World.h is included under Box2D/Dynamics/b2World.h so that shouldn't be a problem. Tried adding that one specifically but it didn't work.

Comment: @user3267110 Are you sure this is a compiler error and not your linker complaining about missing implementations?

Comment: Well if I comment out the "world = new b2World(gravity)" I can compile without any problems. I can still reach b2Vec2.. So I should be able to get b2World aswell, right?

Comment: fixed it.. Had forgotten to link in -.-' thanks for the help mate!

Comment: can you tell me how exactly you solved the problem ? I am facing the same problem and being clueless about the solution.